# Load Unmanaged DLL in Designer to load Wrapped Controls

Tags: c#, dll, unmanaged, windows-forms-designer

Is there any way to load unmanaged dll during design-time in visual studio?

I know that I can always place the DLL in the "System32" folder or add the Dll path to the "PATH" variable to load it directly. But I dont want to do that. I want to load it from the ExecutablePath of the Application. The DLL actually holds a control.

Can anyone help me with this situation??

---

Thanks,
WritZ

Comment: You may have to PInvoke it from the executable path, and build the designer yourself. The VS designer simply creates a .designer.cs file, which you can write manually as well.

Comment: I want to use the Designer of the VS! Thats why I am asking if there is any other way to accomplish this! Or I would just have used a "Blank Application" template not the "Windows Forms Project"! And if i try to edit the `*.designer.cs` file then i think vs will overwrite it as i have experienced such problems before!

Comment: I didn't mean overwriting the *.designer.cs file, but instead the designer file simply creates a partial class file, which you can put in another file. Unmanaged code is invoked at runtime, which is why the designer can't see/use it, since it is not able to be generated in the VS designer. This is the same reason why DLLs can be swapped out without recompiling the application.

Comment: Yes, I know that the designer file contains the partial class of the form. Yes, "Unmanaged code is invoked at runtime", but when i add a control [contained by the dll [wrapped by another .net dll]] in the designer it just does not work and show an error message box! So, I am asking if there is a way to pre-load a dll in the designer from the Application Path! [I am not going to manually re-write the designer myself for this small work!]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to load it from the ExecutablePath of the Application

That cannot work, there isn't one yet.  Other than Windows never looking there, the designer is guaranteed to fail when you check-in from source control or clean the project.

This code runs in the context of Visual Studio so Windows DLL search rules are based on its install location.  It isn't clear whether this is pinvoke code that's failing or if your assembly has an implicit dependency on the DLL.  You can do something about pinvoke, you can prevent code running by testing the DesignMode property.  The only way to deal with an implicit dependency is helping Windows find the DLL.  A directory on the search path.  The only way forward then is to split code into the parts that only really matter at design mode so DesignMode becomes useful again.